# Unable to load a Python package via a file

Tags: python, graphite

I am trying to load a file having these contents:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/opt/graphite/webapp')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'graphite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Target WSGI script '/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

When I bring up Python on the command line and try to load this module as follows, I get no error:

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

I checked the permissions for django and all its subdirectories. Any ideas?

These are the errors in apache:

```
Thu Aug 20 14:37:23 2015] [info] [client 26.16.7.183] mod_wsgi (pid=1812, process='graphite', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi'.
[Thu Aug 20 14:37:23 2015] [error] [client 26.16.7.183] mod_wsgi (pid=1812): Target WSGI script '/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Aug 20 14:37:23 2015] [error] [client 26.16.7.183] mod_wsgi (pid=1812): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi'.
[Thu Aug 20 14:37:23 2015] [error] [client 26.16.7.183] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Aug 20 14:37:23 2015] [error] [client 26.16.7.183]   File "/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[Thu Aug 20 14:37:23 2015] [error] [client 26.16.7.183]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Thu Aug 20 14:37:23 2015] [error] [client 26.16.7.183] ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Thu Aug 20 14:37:23 2015] [debug] mod_headers.c(743): headers: ap_headers_output_filter()
```

this is my graphite.conf for apache:

================

```
Listen 8090
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_wsgi.so
WSGISocketPrefix /etc/apache2/wsgi
<Directory /opt/graphite/webapp>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/opt/graphite/webapp"
#
<VirtualHost *:8090>
        ServerName 192.168.101.2
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        DocumentRoot "/opt/graphite/webapp"
        WSGIDaemonProcess graphite processes=20 threads=20 display-name='%{GROUP}' inactivity-timeout=120
        WSGIProcessGroup graphite
#
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIImportScript /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi process-group=graphite application-group=%{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi
        Alias /static/ /opt/graphite/webapp/content/
        <Location "/content/">
                 SetHandler None
        </Location>
#
        Alias /media/ "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"
#
        <Location "/media/">
                 SetHandler None
        </Location>
        <Directory /opt/graphite/conf/>
           Allow from all
        </Directory>
#
LogLevel debug
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/graphite_error
</VirtualHost>
```

It keeps giving me error about this file:

```
/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi

[Fri Aug 21 13:04:52 2015] [info] [client 29.0.213.18] mod_wsgi (pid=11626, process='graphite', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi'.
[Fri Aug 21 13:04:52 2015] [error] [client 29.0.213.18] mod_wsgi (pid=11626): Target WSGI script '/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Aug 21 13:04:52 2015] [error] [client 29.0.213.18] mod_wsgi (pid=11626): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi'.
```

when I am on the shell and issue:

```
python /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi
```

I get no error. Not sure what the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is likely going to be because mod_wsgi is compiled for and bound to a different Python version/installation than you intend to use. It therefore isn't looking at the spot where you installed all your packages.

What Python version are you wanting to use and what do you get for:

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
print(sys.prefix)
```

when running that from the interpreter.

Then work out what version of Python mod_wsgi is using:

- https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library
- https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use

---

UPDATE 1

To check where the `django` module is coming from normally from command line Python, so you can see whether you are using the same Python installation as mod_wsgi is compiled for and using, you would in the interpreter do:

```
>>> import django
>>> print django.__file__
/some/path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc
```

Modules should have the `__file__` attribute, with the exception of builtin modules which are static linked into the Python binary.

So the `django` module must have one.

Comment: there is only one version of python 2.6.9

Comment: print (sys.prefix) says /usr and print(sys.path) shows my packages under /usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages and /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ is this right?

Comment: From your command line Python, if you import django module and print out ``django.__file__`` what is that directory and is the parent of it in ``sys.path`` of code running under mod_wsgi.

Comment: print django._file_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_file_'

Comment: Still the seam errors, I compiled the mod_wsgi as per documentation. Still "ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi" errors

Comment: Did you do the ``django.__fille__`` check above? What did you get?

Comment: it looks like httpd2-worker was missing, after installing it, and compiling no more errors. Sorry for the noice, thanks again for  your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your are probably loading the `/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi` through a webserver or something. Can you show us what you do when you get this error.

Have you checked `/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi` is executable ?

`chmod +x /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi`

The import of `import django.core.handlers.wsgi` is working fine. But thats not where the error is located. The actual error is, that whatever you are using cannot load the file `/opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi` as python module not any django module.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 204 Aug 20 13:48 /opt/graphite/conf/graphite.wsgi

Comment: yes, I am trying to load this file via http. I placed the errors to the post.

Comment: Ok now i know why you are testing the import of django ... :)
Are you using a virtualenv or have you installed django gobally ? If using a virtualenv you have to set `WSGIPythonHome` in you apache config to the correct virtualenv.

Comment: any ideas how to address this?

Comment: Sorry, hit return too fast :) see comment above

Comment: I just installed django as a package and it is in the site-packages as egg and also there is djanog directory. I dont think I am using virtualenv.

Comment: I think graphite is providing an example apache conf, are you using this one ? Can you post your config here ?

Comment: I posted the apache graphite.conf file to the post.

Comment: Under mod_wsgi, the WSGI script files do not need to be executable.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton well on a default Ubuntu install it doesn't work, and if you set it to be executable then it does.

Comment: If you are having to make the script executable, that is more likely to imply it is being executed as a CGI script and that it is not in fact a WSGI script file.

Answer (score 0):

Being new to Python but having recently done battle with Netbeans trying to figure out why a java module was loading wrong, I learned that multiple java versions exist on my Ubuntu 14.04 box. For example, 
~$ whereis python -- told me of multiple locations
~$ which python -- gave me /usr/bin/python

So, could your IDE be using a different python? One that, in the terminal, finds the path but not in the IDE?