# WSGI script cannot be loaded in openSuse Server

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, wsgi, django-wsgi

The error appears only in openSuse Server 12.3 x64 (minimal installation). The same code with the same apache settings works like charm with Ubuntu distribution. Several errors appear while running the django project.

#### Error: While accessing page url "500 Internal Server Error"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
mod_wsgi (pid=4601): Target WSGI script '/srv/www/compare/htdocs/config/apache/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=4601): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/www/compare/htdocs/config/apache/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/var/www/thehomeboard/wwwhome/wsgi.py", line 37, in <module>
       application = get_wsgi_application()
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
       django.setup()
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
       raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
        raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

#### Error: While running python wsgi.py. (The same error appears when running python manage.py)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/www/compare/htdocs/config/apache/wsgi.py", line 28, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 112, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/apps.py", line 6, in <module>
    from debug_toolbar import settings as dt_settings
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/settings.py", line 8, in <module>
    from debug_toolbar.compat import import_module
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/compat.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.test import (  # NOQA
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.test.client import Client, RequestFactory
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 22, in <module>
    from django.test import signals
ImportError: cannot import name signals
```

Configuration of the project looks like this:

#### VirtualHost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName compare.django

  DocumentRoot /srv/www/compare/htdocs
  ErrorLog /srv/www/compare/log/error.log
  CustomLog /srv/www/compare/log/custom.log combined

  WSGIDaemonProcess compare python-path=/srv/www/compare/htdocs:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages processes=2 threads=5

  WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/compare/htdocs/config/apache/wsgi.py
  <Directory /srv/www/compare/htdocs>
      <Files wsgi.py>
        #Require all granted
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
      </Files>
  </Directory>

  <Directory /srv/www/compare/htdocs/config/apache>
      WSGIProcessGroup compare
      #Require all granted
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  Alias /static/ /srv/www/compare/htdocs/static/
  <Directory /srv/www/compare/htdocs/static>
      #Require all granted
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  Alias /storage/ /srv/www/compare/htdocs/storage/
  <Directory /srv/www/compare/htdocs/storage>
      #Require all granted
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

#### wsgi.py

```
import os, sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# Calculate the path based on the location of the WSGI script.
apache_configuration = os.path.dirname(__file__)
project = os.path.dirname(apache_configuration)
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)

sys.path.append(workspace)
sys.path.append(project)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Python environment info:

#### mod_wsgi settings

```
$ldd /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_wsgi.so 
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff67947000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f698c085000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f698be69000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f698babb000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f698b8b7000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f698b6b4000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f698b3b5000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f698c651000)

python import sys, django
print sys.prefix # '/usr'
print sys.version # '2.7.3 (default, Apr 14 2012, 08:58:41) [GCC]'
print sys.version_info # 'sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)'
print django.__file__ # '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc'
```

Comment: does ./manage.py work on it?

Comment: it does not work it throws "ImportError: cannot import name signals" from django.test import signals

Comment: Right then, you have a simpler problem. remove apache from the mix. Start with basic manage.py, but first why on earh are you importing stuff from django.test ??

Comment: Edit the question, do manage.py runserver and post the stacktrace direct (not as a gist) and change the tags as appropriate you will get a better response.

Comment: importing stuff from django.test it is internal import executed when running django project (

Comment: As discussed lets leave apache out of this. It simplifies the problem in a big big way. And your wall of code on this question becomes smaller so a lot more people might actually bother to read it. Secondly your test client import appears to be from debug toolbar, why not disable it till you sort this out?

Comment: My project runs in VirtualBox (development server). VirtualBox imitates the production server.  Nevertheless, I found the solution for my problem, and it is related to how the Python is installed (pre-installed), in openSuse Server, and how it comply with mod_wsgi. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution for my problem turned out to be related to the way how Python is installed (pre-installed) in openSuse Server 12.3 and how it comply with ***mod_wsgi*** installation.

#### How I get to the solution

Facts that I know. The project works in Ubuntu environment, and it does not work on openSuse. Thus, there must be something external related to source code that prevents it for working. The only external thing is environment. I googled the errors related to "Target WSGI script not being loaded as Python module.", "RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant"), and I found series of post related to mod_wsgi. Finally, the most reasonable answer was posted by Graham Dumpleton [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125658/unable-to-load-a-python-package-via-a-file#answer-32129395).

Going deeper I found [modwsgi wiki and installation issues](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues) where I found additional information in paragraph ***Lack Of Python Shared Library***. The output of ***ldd*** command shown in installation issues differed with my output of ***mod_wsgi.so*** file. This made me think that pre-installed Python in openSuse is not using shared library. From there I decided to install Python form source.

#### Solution Implementation

1. First I removed all traces of python installation founded in openSuse

   ```
   zypper rm python 
   zypper rm python-base
   zypper rm python-distribute
   zypper rm libpython
   ```
2. Installed Python from source. Following this [instructions](http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2013/05/12/building-python-2-dot-7-4-on-sles-10-sp3/), and remember to add ***--enable-shared*** flag as Graham mentioned in the ***installation issues***
3. I installed requirements.txt related to project and I ***rebooted*** the system. Restarting apache does not solve the issue.

These are the steps leading to solving my problems. I hope that It will save  you some gray hair.

Along, I had some small problems with installation the Python from source, but these problems were easily googled and fixed on the way.